# Populate Razor DropDownList with Object passed from Controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I saw a couple of questions about this stuff but there is no one clear for me. I have this:

Currencies.cs

```
public class Currencies
{
    public WorldCurrencies.CurrencyTypes Get()
    {
        var url = "http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json";
        var currencies = _download_serialized_json_data<CurrencyTypes>(url);

        return currencies;
    }

    private static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new()
    {
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            var res = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

WebAPIController.cs

```
public class WebAPIController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Converter()
    {
        WorldCurrencies.Currencies curr = new WorldCurrencies.Currencies();

        return View("Index", curr.Get());
    }
}
```

And Index.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fromC">From Currency</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownList("Prueba", Model, )
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to populate the DropDownList with the object called currencies, but I don't have a clear idea of how to implement this.

Any clues?

**EDIT:** This is exactly what curr.Get() returns:

```
    res {WorldCurrencies.CurrencyTypes} WorldCurrencies.CurrencyTypes
    AED "United Arab Emirates Dirham"   string
    AFN "Afghan Afghani"    string
    ALL "Albanian Lek"  string
    AMD "Armenian Dram" string
    ANG "Netherlands Antillean Guilder" string
    AOA "Angolan Kwanza"    string
    ARS "Argentine Peso"    string
    AUD "Australian Dollar" string
    AWG "Aruban Florin" string
    AZN "Azerbaijani Manat" string
    BAM "Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark"   string
    BBD "Barbadian Dollar"  string
    BDT "Bangladeshi Taka"  string
    BGN "Bulgarian Lev" string
    ...
```

Comment: What have you tried and failed? The [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738.aspx) method is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Prueba", Model, )    ?

Comment: I'd put money on the fact that the curr.Get() doesn't return the equivalent of IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it one thing a time.

> What is the format of your data?

It is an object like this:

```
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    "ANG": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder"
}
```

So we have a bag with key/value pairs, the key is the currency's code and the value is the currency's name.

> How can we deserialize this?

As simple as below:

```
var res = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(json_data);
```

> What do we want to show in our View?

At least a dropdown with all the available currencies. If you need more data to show, you have to add the extra properties in the Model and initialize them correspondingly, when you create the model.

> How can we achieve this?

```
@model CurrencyModel

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fromC">From Currency</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownList("Currencies", CurrencyModel.Currencies)
    </div>
</div>
```

> What do we need?

A model with at least one property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` called `Currencies`:

```
public class CurrencyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Currencies { get; set; }
}
```

> Who will create this model ?

This responsibility belongs to the controller.

```
public class WebAPIController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Converter()
    {
        var currencies = new CurrenciesRepository.GetAll();

        var currencyModel = new CurrencyModel
        {
            Currencies =
                currencies.Select(currency => new SelectListItem {
                                                  Text = currency.Value, 
                                                   Value = currency.Key});
        }
        return View("Index", currencyModel);
    }
}
```

**What it is needed now** is to create one new class the `CurrenciesRepository`

```
public class CurrenciesRepository
{
    string _url = "http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json";

    public IDictionary<string, string> GetAll()
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = webClient.DownloadString(_url);
            var currencies= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(data);

            return currencies;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to send you a beer or something to thank you. So thank you, again for the explanation for dummies. I had to learn C# in one month at my work place and is kind of difficult to implement everything now... Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: @Tincho.UY you are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)